# FreeRadius , How to exclude certain urls from accounting packet

Tags: cisco, freeradius, radius, diameter-protocol, free-diameter

I have many users doing Authentication + Accounting packet sent from Network Device [LNS] to freeradius server.

in the accounting packet, client send's how much KB used in their current session.

I have a limit for each user and this limit gets decreased on each accounting packet sent  and i stop the user when their limit is reached .

how can I exclude certain URLs from being added into Accounting Packet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it on RADIUS - it only recieve that NAS sends to it. You can do in on few network access types, that uses queues to account, ie hotspots, by adding walled garden rule. But not l2tp - it sends bytes on interface.

Usual way to account this is NetFlow. It sends accounting data for each connection.